# How to create two instances in different rack in EC2? (Rack awareness in AWS)

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I am trying to create a Hadoop cluster. I am using a modified Hadoop source which will schedule tasks to different racks based on the workload of a rack. To test this, I want half my Datanodes to be on one rack and other half to be on a different rack. How can I ensure this?

Comment: Are you using Amazon EMR or are you deploying and managing your own Hadoop cluster?

Comment: By "rack", are you referring to traditional IT infrastructure where computers fit within a rack, sharing some resources (eg power feed)? Or is this a Hadoop term?

Comment: Hadoop defines nodes to be in the same rack if they are in the same network switch. 
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/RackAwareness.html

Comment: It would not be capable of detecting a physical rack within the Amazon EC2 infrastructure. That documentation mentions some assumptions about address ranges that would not be true within EC2.

Comment: Note that EC2 does not run on a switched network.  It's a software-defined network that emulates ordinary Ethernet.

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of a "rack" on Amazon EC2. The only level of control you have is the **Availability Zone**, which is a physically distinct data center. However, Hadoop clusters are always run in the same AZ to improve speed and also because, if the master node fails, the whole cluster fails. (This is on EMR -- if you have deployed your own cluster, you could go multi-AZ.)

If your concern is to **avoid multiple outages**, my advice would be "don't worry!". Hadoop is designed to handle failure, so if a node fails it will send work to the remaining nodes. You can provision additional nodes to the cluster to replace failed nodes but this is not done automatically.

Rather than putting "half my datanodes to be on one rack and other half to be on a different rack", it's quite likely that each node will be on a different host computer so you'll probably get a **wider spread of infrastructure** there merely having two 'racks'. However, you have no visibility into such placement.

Also, it is recommended that you **store persistent data in Amazon S3 rather than in HDFS**. This way, you can terminate the cluster and your data is still available and, worst case, if the cluster fails your data is still available too. This is better than a normal on-premises Hadoop deployment that cannot suffer loss of HDFS.

**Bottom line:** Don't worry about it. Deploy your clusters and monitor them to see whether failure is actually a concern.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. I am however trying to test my load-balancing algorithm for different racks. I made some changes to source to open container requests on a rack based on its workload. To test it I want to create a cluster with two racks with some nodes in each.

Answer (score 1):

### You can do it through Spread Placement Group

1. create a Spread Placement Groups first.
2. launch instances and specify them belongs to this spread group.

### AWS Documentation

> A spread placement group is a group of instances that are each placed on distinct racks, with each rack having its own network and power source.
>
> The following image shows seven instances in a single Availability Zone that are placed into a spread placement group. The seven instances are placed on seven different racks.
>
> Spread placement groups are recommended for applications that have a small number of critical instances that should be kept separate from each other. Launching instances in a spread placement group reduces the risk of simultaneous failures that might occur when instances share the same racks. Spread placement groups provide access to distinct racks, and are therefore suitable for mixing instance types or launching instances over time.
>
> A spread placement group can span multiple Availability Zones in the same Region. You can have a maximum of seven running instances per Availability Zone per group.
>
> If you start or launch an instance in a spread placement group and there is insufficient unique hardware to fulfill the request, the request fails. Amazon EC2 makes more distinct hardware available over time, so you can try your request again later.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html

### A introduction to three placement groups

[Amazon EC2 Placement Groups: SAA-C02 AWS Certified Solutions Architect Associate Exam 2020](https://youtu.be/jnpDHVvRbEc?t=247)